# How to get a kotlin package by reflection

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Kotlin reflection library defines `KDeclarationContainer`, which `Represents an entity which may contain declarations of any other entities, such as a class or a package.`

`this::class` returns `KClass`, which extends `KDeclarationContainer`, but how do I get the parent `KDeclarationContainer` (a `KPackage`?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `KPackage` in kotlin now, but you can get a java `Package` instead, for example:

```
val pkg:Package = this::class.java.`package`
```

**IF** you really want to get a `KPackageImpl` instance, you can get it from `kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection`, but it doesn't make sense, because Kotlin reflect is **incomplete** yet, for example:

```
val pkg = Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinPackage(this::class.java, "")
//  ^--- there is no methods to get package information like as java.lang.Package,
//       since it is a `KDeclarationContainer` rather than a `KPackage`
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a kotlin equivalent. The check-in comment on https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/core/builtins/src/kotlin/reflect actually mentions a `KPackage`

Comment: Any progress on this in the last 5 years? I still don't see a `package` field on `KClass`.